# Sorting HashMap into TreeMap: custom Comparator removes values with the same key

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator

I'm trying to sort a `HashMap<String, Long>`. I'm have the following code for sorting:

```
private static class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String>{
            HashMap<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String, Long>();

            public ValueComparator(HashMap<String, Long> map){
                this.map.putAll(map);
            }

            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                if(map.get(s1) > map.get(s2)){
                    System.out.println("s1: " + s1 + "; s2: " + s2);
                    return -1;
                }
                else if (map.get(s1).equals(map.get(s2))) {
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }

private static TreeMap<String, Long> sortMapByValue(HashMap<String, Long> map){
                Comparator<String> comparator = new ValueComparator(map);
                //TreeMap is a map sorted by its keys.
                //The comparator is used to sort the TreeMap by keys.
                TreeMap<String, Long> result = new TreeMap<String, Long>(comparator);
                result.putAll(map);

                System.out.println("DONE sort");
                return result;
        }
```

The problem is, when several different keys have the same values, only one of the key makes it into the final map:

**EXAMPLE:**

```
 public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        HashMap<String, Long> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("Cat", (long) 4);
        hashMap.put("Human", (long) 2);
        hashMap.put("Dog", (long) 4);
        hashMap.put("Fish", (long) 0);
        hashMap.put("Tree", (long) 1);
        hashMap.put("Three-legged-human", (long) 3);
        hashMap.put("Monkey", (long) 2);

        System.out.println(hashMap);  //7 pairs

        System.out.println(sortMapByValue(hashMap));  //5 pairs
   }
}
```

How would I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's fixable you are using the the maps in an unintended way and breaking contracts.  Tree map is expecting to be sorted by the key and the key is expected to be unique so when the compare == 0 it will just override the node's value.  You can always implement your own TreeMap and make it do whatever you want it to.

I'm not sure what you want to do with it but I think you need something like

```
TreeMap<Long,List<String>>
```

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java

```
    if (cpr != null) {
        do {
            parent = t;
            cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                t = t.left;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                t = t.right;
            else
                return t.setValue(value);
        } while (t != null);
```